# Wordpress sharify plugin - og:image tag not working?

Tags: wordpress

My test page is: http://iglesiabautistaesperanza.org/?p=107

I have an og:image tag set in the header as you can see by viewing the code. When I open this image using that link, it is the right image (Iglesia Bautista Esperanza on a transparent background). However, whenever I try to use the SHARE button it pulls in some other random logo file which has the name twice on an orange background. The Facebook debugger shows the same incorrect image, although it also shows the og:image tag as being the only tag and with the correct link.

I'm baffled. Any help is appreciated!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/sharify/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Figlesiabautistaesperanza.org%2F%3Fp%3D107) first?

Take in consideration everytime you update the og:image on your side you won't see the changes directly on the facebook share unless you run through the debugger, which in that case will clean its cache for you and pull the latest data.

The logo I can see it is pulling is the correct one, however you are trying to link a .gif image with a transparent background. My guess here is that facebook tries to convert the logo into a .png, going through the convert process it picks up the orange from the second line and it applies that to the background making the second line invisible to you.

I would suggest to upload a PNG logo maybe with a white solid background and try again through the facebook debugger first.

Comment: That was exactly the right answer!  I created a new PNG file with a white background and then refreshed the scrape data on the Facebook debugger and now it is showing correctly.  Thanks a lot for that!